# How to make the argument $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} (a + b^k) = a, 0< b < 1$ for matrices

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, proof-writing, normed-spaces

Suppose $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then we can easily see that $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} (a + b^k) = a,  0< b < 1$

Suppose we have $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $\|B\| < 1$

and attempt to solve the question:

$\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} (A + B^k) = ?$

We could normify the equation to have

$\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \|A + B^k\| \leq \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \|A\| + \|B\|^k \leq \|A\|$

We could even say that $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \|A + B^k\| = \|A\|$

But how does that help with the original question: $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} (A + B^k) = ?$

Since we cannot recover $A$ from the norm of $A = \|A\|$ (since $\| \cdot \|$ does not biject), how can we make the argument that $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} (A + B^k) = A$?

What is a good way to show $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} (A + B^k) = A$ for $\|B\| < 1$?

Comment: The limit is $A$ if the limit of $(A+B^k)-A=B^k$ is $0$. That seems fairly trivial if $\lVert B\rVert<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $\lim_{k\to\infty}X_k=Y$ if $\lim_{k\to\infty}\|X_k-Y\|=0$. So, in your case, you need to show that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\|A+B^k-A\|=0$, or $\lim_{k\to\infty}\|B^k\|=0$. Now the latter statement is true if the norm is *submultiplicative*, because $\|B^k\|\le\|B\|^k$ and $\|B\|<1$. In this case $\lim_{k\to\infty}(A+B^k)=A$.

If the matrix norm is not submultiplicative, $A+B^k$ may fail to converge. E.g. consider the case where $A=0$, $B$ is the $2\times2$ rotation matrix for $1$ radian. When $\|\cdot\|$ is one fourth of the Frobenius norm, we have $\|B\|=\frac12<1$, but $A+B^k=\pmatrix{\cos k&-\sin k\\ \sin k&\cos k}$ diverges.